# Vinyl siding replacement - Sizing / Ordering help!

Tags: vinyl

I recently took on a project to replace my old deck with composite. With that, the original builders nailed two posts directly to the house and cut a hole in the vinyl siding. I am repairing it now, but am having a difficult time finding the correct vinyl. From my measurements I have:

4.5 Inch double traditional in Pebble (to be exact) vinyl with a 4 inch outside corner as well.

Everything I see at the box stores are either 3 or 4 inch only, no 4.5 inch. The only 4.5 inch vinyl I found was "dutch lap" and not my more normal, "traditional" one that is more flat. For note, my house was built 1999, so not exactly super old!

I appreciate any help, I am simply looking to order some and install it before it snows. I even have matched paint of the siding from Home Depot should I find some that are not the correct color.

Comment: Contact a local lumber yard, they're great at sourcing this type of stuff.

Comment: Please post a picture.